# Get Id of Row that Matches Regex with data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, filter, custom-data-attribute

I have a function that:

1. filters tr rows
2. Makes an approved regex based on the value passed into the function
3. Makes an `rtnData` array consisting of what I believe is a row that has a data-attr matching the approved regex.

What I want is just the id's of the matching rows rather than what `rtnData` is doing.

```
function filterPay(val){
        // target Rows
            $(".loading tr").hide().filter(function() {

        var rtnData = "";
        //make approved regex based on given value
        var payApproved=    new RegExp(val.map(x => x.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')).join('|'), 'i');

           //make rtnData array? consisting of rows that match regex
            rtnData = (
                        $(this).attr("data-payment").match(payApproved)
            );

        return rtnData;

        }).fadeIn("fast");
    }

//I know this refers to the unique Id of each row but don't know how to 
// chain it with the match selection
console.log($(this).attr('data-row'));
```

So instead of showing the rows is it possible to just get the id's and push them row into a new array, because after this I have to match that array to another filter array and only show the rows where the 2 arrays have matching id's.

Answer (score 1):

Your code filters a list of `tr` to those whose `data-payment` is matched by the regular expression. You now only need to do a `map` on the results and extract the id.

Also you should not create the regular expression inside the `filter` since it is not affected by each `tr`

```js
function filterPay(val) {
  var payApproved = new RegExp(val.map(x => x.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')).join('|'), 'i');

  // target Rows
  var rows = $(".loading tr").hide().filter(function() {
      // only use test if the reguar expression does not have the global flag set
      return payApproved.test($(this).attr("data-payment"));
  }).fadeIn("fast");
  var ids = rows.get().map(function(row){return row.id});
}
```